# Multiple page pdf to single png using ghostscript

Tags: imagemagick, ghostscript

I am trying to convert a multi page pdf to png using following command

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=png256 -r600x600  -sOutputFile=out.png in.pdf
```

However it only converts the first page. I can pass a %d in out%d.png to get multiple pages, but I want a single png output. Is that possible ? I am aware of convert utility of imagemagick which does that (using gs as a delegate), but I want to do directly using gs.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't aware it was possible to have a PNG file which contains mutliple different images. As far as I am aware it is not possible to produce such a file with Ghostscript.